# C# ServiceStack post Deadlock

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, servicestack, deadlock

I am calling an API many times per second. Its causing deadlocks. Can anyone propose a solution to solving this?  I am running .netcore 2.2 MVC service

```
   public async Task Post(DeviceEndpointInsertTemp request)
        {
            //Check if device exists
            var q = Db.From<Device>(Db.TableAlias("d"))
                  .LeftJoin<Company>((device, company) =>
                      device.CompanyId == company.Id, Db.TableAlias("Company"))
                  .Where<Device>(d => Sql.TableAlias(d.DeviceNumber, "d") == request.DeviceNumber)
                  .Select<IntegrationDeviceCompany>(d => new
                  {
                      Id = Sql.TableAlias(d.Id, "d"),
                      CompanyId = Sql.TableAlias(d.CompanyId, "d"),
                      ModelCode = Sql.TableAlias(d.ModelCode, "d"),
                      DataUpdateTime = Sql.TableAlias(d.DataUpdateTime, "Company")
                  });
            var result = await Db.SingleAsync<IntegrationDeviceCompany>(q);
            if (result != null)
            {
                DeviceUpdateTemp deviceUpdateTemp = new DeviceUpdateTemp();
                deviceUpdateTemp.EventType = "device-update";
                deviceUpdateTemp.CompanyId = result.CompanyId;
                deviceUpdateTemp.DeviceId = result.Id;
                deviceUpdateTemp.DeviceNumber = request.DeviceNumber;
                deviceUpdateTemp.AuditId = 0;
                deviceUpdateTemp.AuditStamp = request.EventGridPostDateTime;
                deviceUpdateTemp.PickDateTime = DateTime.UtcNow.AddSeconds(result.DataUpdateTime);

                //get endpoints by device id
                var iOSetups = await Db.SelectAsync<IOSetups>(ios => ios.DeviceId == result.Id && ios.Enabled == "1");
                foreach (NameValuePair nameValuePair in request.IOEndpointList)
                {
                    if (iOSetups != null)
                    {
                        IOSetups endpointResult = null;
                        string ioNum = Regex.Replace(nameValuePair.Name, "[^0-9]+", string.Empty);
                        string ioTypeName = (string.IsNullOrEmpty(ioNum)) ? nameValuePair.Name : nameValuePair.Name.Replace(ioNum, string.Empty);
                        string ioTypeId = GetIOTypeId(ioTypeName);
                        //localIONum/DevIONum not required for vin since there will be always only one record for vin
                        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(ioNum) && ioTypeName.ToLower() == "vin")
                        {
                            endpointResult = iOSetups.FirstOrDefault(ios => ios.IoTypeID == ioTypeId);
                        }
                        //48 -> X-400, 55 -> X-404
                        //Use localIONum property for X-400 and X-404
                        else if (result.ModelCode == "48" || result.ModelCode == "55")
                        {
                            endpointResult = iOSetups.FirstOrDefault(ios => ios.IoTypeID == ioTypeId && ios.LocalIONum == ioNum);
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            //Use DevIONum property for other model type
                            endpointResult = iOSetups.FirstOrDefault(ios => ios.IoTypeID == ioTypeId && ios.DevIONum == ioNum);
                        }
                        if (endpointResult != null)
                        {
                            deviceUpdateTemp.EndPointId = endpointResult.EndPointId;
                            deviceUpdateTemp.OldValue = endpointResult.Value;
                        }
                    }
                    deviceUpdateTemp.NameCamelCase = nameValuePair.Name;
                    deviceUpdateTemp.Value = nameValuePair.Value;
                    Db.InsertAsync(deviceUpdateTemp);
                }
            }

        }
```

STDOUT from webserver

```
: Ben.Diagnostics.BlockingMonitor[6]
      Blocking method has been invoked and blocked, this can lead to threadpool starvation.
         at System.Threading.Tasks.TplEtwProvider.TaskWaitBegin(Int32 OriginatingTaskSchedulerID, Int32 OriginatingTaskID, Int32 TaskID, TaskWaitBehavior Behavior, Int32 ContinueWithTaskID)
         at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.InternalWaitCore(Int32 millisecondsTimeout, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
         at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Wait(Int32 millisecondsTimeout, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
         at Serilog.Sinks.PeriodicBatching.PeriodicBatchingSink.EmitBatch(IEnumerable`1 events)
         at Serilog.Sinks.PeriodicBatching.PeriodicBatchingSink.OnTick()
         at Serilog.Sinks.PeriodicBatching.PeriodicBatchingSink.<.ctor>b__8_0(CancellationToken cancel)
         at Serilog.Sinks.PeriodicBatching.PortableTimer.OnTick()
         at Serilog.Sinks.PeriodicBatching.PortableTimer.<.ctor>b__6_0(Object _)
         at System.Threading.TimerQueueTimer.<>c.<.cctor>b__22_0(Object state)
         at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state)
         at System.Threading.TimerQueueTimer.CallCallback()
         at System.Threading.TimerQueueTimer.Fire()
         at System.Threading.TimerQueue.FireNextTimers()
         at System.Threading.TimerQueue.AppDomainTimerCallback(Int32 id)

Hosting environment: AzureDev
Content root path: D:\home\site\wwwroot
Now listening on: http://127.0.0.1:17717
Application started. Press Ctrl+C to shut down.
info: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Internal.WebHost[1]
      Request starting HTTP/1.1 GET http://*****/API/ServiceStatusWithDbCheck  
info: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Internal.WebHost[1]
      Request starting HTTP/1.1 GET http://*****/API/ServiceStatusWithDbCheck  
infoinfo: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Internal.WebHost[1]
      Request starting HTTP/1.1 POST http://*****/API/Integration/DeleteCompanyCertificateToken application/json 2
info: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Internal.WebHost[1]
      Request starting HTTP/1.1 POST http://*****/API/Integration/DeviceEndpointInsertTemp application/json 536
info: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Internal.WebHost[1]
      Request starting HTTP/1.1 POST http://*****/API/Integration/DeviceEndpointInsertTemp application/json 536
info: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Internal.WebHost[1]
      Request starting HTTP/1.1 POST http://*****/API/Integration/DeviceEndpointInsertTemp application/json 536
info: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Internal.WebHost[1]
      Request starting HTTP/1.1 POST http://*****/API/Integration/DeviceEndpointInsertTemp application/json 536
info: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Internal.WebHost[1]
      Request starting HTTP/1.1 POST http://*****/API/Integration/DeviceEndpointInsertTemp application/json 536
info: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Internal.WebHost[1]
      Request starting HTTP/1.1 POST http://*****/API/Integration/DeviceEndpointInsertTemp application/json 536
info: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Internal.WebHost[1]
      Request starting HTTP/1.1 POST http://*****/API/Integration/DeviceEndpointInsertTemp application/json 536
: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Internal.WebHost[1]
      Request starting HTTP/1.1 POST http://*****/API/Integration/DeleteCompanyCertificateToken application/json 2
info: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Internal.WebHost[1]
      Request starting HTTP/1.1 POST http://*****/API/Integration/DeviceEndpointInsertTemp application/json 536
info: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Internal.WebHost[1]
      Request starting HTTP/1.1 POST http://*****/API/Integration/DeviceEndpointInsertTemp application/json 536
info: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Internal.WebHost[1]
      Request starting HTTP/1.1 POST http://*****/API/Integration/DeviceEndpointInsertTemp application/json 536
info: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Internal.WebHost[1]
      Request starting HTTP/1.1 POST http://*****/API/Integration/DeviceEndpointInsertTemp application/json 536
info: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Internal.WebHost[1]
      Request starting HTTP/1.1 POST http://*****/API/Integration/DeviceEndpointInsertTemp application/json 536
info: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Internal.WebHost[1]
      Request starting HTTP/1.1 POST http://*****/API/Integration/DeviceEndpointInsertTemp application/json 536
info: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Internal.WebHost[1]
      Request starting HTTP/1.1 POST http://*****/API/Integration/DeviceEndpointInsertTemp application/json 536
infoinfo: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Internal.WebHost[2]
      Request finished in 1254.2787ms 200 text/html
: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Internal.WebHost[2]
      Request finished in 1254.2787ms 200 text/html
warn: Ben.Diagnostics.BlockingMonitor[6]
```

Comment: Remove `.Result` and `.Wait` from code not shown here... There is not much else can be suggested without true [MCVE].

Comment: Why is `Db.InsertAsync(deviceUpdateTemp)` not awaited?

Comment: I don't see any .Result or .Wait. I just awaited the code.

Comment: Db.InsertAsync(deviceUpdateTemp), i removed the await as it was the last call and thought it would maybe help stop the entire method from deadlocking, and it does not need to call back to the method.

Comment: Never leave dangling async tasks like your Db.InsertAsync, either await it or return it so your async method callee awaits it. You're going to need to [debug and profile your App](https://michaelscodingspot.com/how-to-debug-net-deadlocks-c-deadlocks-in-depth-part-3/) to find out where it's being dead locked.

Comment: I figured this out finally. It was some code in my errorlog handler. a call was calling it without auth internally. The when it tried to log the error it errored into an infinite loop and no pun.. stackoverflowed.  But nothing was showing me the error or stack traces with that error. I found it accidentally debugging something else. Posting here for anyone who runs into this issue.